# TextBox Properties Like AcceptsReturn or AcceptsTab in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio has made me lazy with all of their rich features, but now I need to code some functionality into PHP.

We have a PHP web page that people are submitting before it is complete because they want to enter a new line in a multiline input control.

The easiest way to fix this, were it Visual Studio, would be to set the [AcceptsReturn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [AcceptsTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptstab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties of a TextBox control to True.

[image: screenshot]

In PHP, I would need some way to configure some kind of text changing event, and I might be better off doing this in JavaScript (or jQuery) ...maybe it can be done in HTML5.

Could someone tell me what it is I need to look for to do this on a non-Windows website platform?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, in PHP, one must turn to Javascript:

```
$('form input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) { // ENTER key
    e.setTempDefault(9); // TAB key
    // e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

This causes the field not to submit when someone presses the ENTER key in a textbox.